# Scope or ajax for queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am not to sure i understand correctly scope in rails. Here what i am trying to do I have a model call article and called tags.

To start off the application it log you in at Article#index action which show all articles. However what I want to be able to refine my view by clicking on a tags that would dynamically be created. The query i would like would be `Article.find(:all, :conditions => ['tags = ?', 'world'])`

How can i achieve this? Or should i just use ajax to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ajax makes sense in this case.

You could have something like this.

**routes.rb**

`match "/articles/tag" => "articles#tag"`

**articles_controller.rb**

```
def tag
  @particularly_tagged_links = Link.find_all_by_tags(params[:tags])
end
```

**application.js** or wherever you are using jquery codes. And trig this function when the user clicks the tag or something.

```
function taggit(tag) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "articles/tags?"+tag
  });
}
```